# Arduino communication stopped working

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, arduino

I am running a small [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) server with Apache 2.2.22 and PHP 5.3.13. My problem is that my JavaScript/Ajax Code is no longer sending the `$POST` to my external PHP file which is supposed to then send the message via serial to my Arduino.

It was working perfectly fine, and then I simply changed the value of the input which is my 'Message' that I'm sending and suddenly it's not happy. I have had this problem before so I just changed the value back to its original, but now even that's not working. I tried to clear all my Web history, re-started WAMP server, and I even re-booted my computer, but none of it worked.

Anyway, here is my code:

#### HTML

```
    <div id="Room1Controls">
        <div id="ControlButton" class="Control1"><a>B
            A
            C
            K</a></div>
        <div class="Room1SwitchContainer">
            <div id="LightsSwitchBox" class="SwitchBox">
            <h1>Lights</h1>
            <input type="checkbox" class="SwitchButton1" value="L11"><a class="SButton1">On</a></input>
            <input type="checkbox" class="SwitchButton2" value="L10"><a class="SButton2">Off</a></input>
        </div>
        <div id="DoorsSwitchBox" class="SwitchBox">
            <h1>Doors</h1>
            <input type="checkbox" class="SwitchButton3" value="D10"><a class="SButton3">Open</a></input>
            <input type="checkbox" class="SwitchButton4" value="D11"><a class="SButton4">Lock</a></input>
        </div>
        <div id="BlindsSwitchBox" class="SwitchBox">
            <h1>Blinds</h1>
            <input type="checkbox" class="SwitchButton5" value="B11"><a class="SButton5">Open</a></input>
            <input type="checkbox" class="SwitchButton6" value="B10"><a class="SButton6">Close</a></input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript/Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var value;
    $(".SButton1").click(function(){
        $(".SwitchButton1").trigger('click');
    });
    $(".SButton2").click(function(){
        $(".SwitchButton2").trigger('click');
    });
    $(".SButton3").click(function(){
        $(".SwitchButton3").trigger('click');
    });
    $(".SButton4").click(function(){
        $(".SwitchButton4").trigger('click');
    });
    $(".SButton5").click(function(){
        $(".SwitchButton5").trigger('click');
    });
    $(".SButton6").click(function(){
        $(".SwitchButton6").trigger('click');
    });
    $("#Room1Controls input").click(function(){
        value=$(this).val();
        $.post('Inc/Parts/arduino.php',{message:value});
    });
});
```

#### PHP

```
<?php
    $message=$_POST['message'];

    if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
        require("php_serial.class.php");
        $serial = new phpSerial();
        $serial->deviceSet("COM3");
        exec('mode COM3 BAUD=96 PARITY=n DATA=8 STOP=1 xon=off octs=off rts=on');
        $serial->deviceOpen();
        if ($_POST['message'] == "L11") {
            $serial->sendMessage("L");
        } else if ($_POST['message'] == "L10") {
            $serial->sendMessage("l");
        } else if ($_POST['message'] == "D10") {
            $serial->sendMessage("D");
        } else if ($_POST['message'] == "D11") {
            $serial->sendMessage("d");
        } else if ($_POST['message'] == "B11") {
            $serial->sendMessage("B");
        } else if ($_POST['message'] == "B10") {
            $serial->sendMessage("b");
        }
        $serial->deviceClose();
    }
?>
```

And the code running on the Arduino Uno:

```
int ldr = 0;
int door = 13;
int blind = 12;
int led = 11;
int in = 0;

void setup() {
    pinMode(door, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(blind, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ldr, INPUT);

    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        in = Serial.read();
    }

    if (in == 'L')
    {
        int val = (analogRead(ldr));
        val = constrain(val, 150, 500);
        int LightLvl = map(val, 150, 500, 255, 0);
        analogWrite(led, LightLvl);
    }
    else
        if (in == 'l') (analogWrite(led, LOW));

    if (in == 'D')
    {
        digitalWrite(door, LOW);
    }
    else
        if (in == 'd') (digitalWrite(door, HIGH));

    if (in == 'B')
    {
      digitalWrite(blind, HIGH);
    }
    else
        if (in == 'b') (digitalWrite(blind, LOW));
}
```

If you could point out any inconsistency or errors in my code that would be great. Also, I am new to coding so if you have any suggestions for how I can improve my code to make it more efficient or alternative ways of doing things I would be very greatful.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious.  I would take a divide and conquer approach to determine where the problem is.  Try replacing your PHP page with one that simply writes the message to a file.  Does the message appear in the file?  On the other end, you may want to try setting the arduino to pulse an LED or something to make sure it is running properly and receiving data.

Comment: Also, sorry if this is obvious, but I've found when working with a breadboard it's really easy to accidentally jiggle the jumpers loose such that they look connected but aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my `.htaccess` file was the problem. I had some script to hide the extensions but for some reason the `$POST` Didn't like it.

Here is the code in the `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If anyone knows a way around this i would love it if you shared it ;)